# how show in table only selected Dimension values

Tags: looker-studio

I have this report showing confirmed cases per selected country.
https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/bb77ba4c-17d6-4501-a2dc-7aab35fd4a8c/page/RtrOB
I have there predefined country : Slovakia ( this is not important)
Next to this chart is table showing top 12 confirmed countries.
My goal is : how to insert in this report  another 1 row table with only selected country stats?

FYI: I have another old report where is showing only  1 row table for  selected country, but when I was checking both reports, I haven't found any difference in edit mode. :) 
And in this old report I have opposite issue: I can't insert table with all countries, :) 
https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/0b717fb6-073d-402d-a051-3acaed79ed00/page/RtrOB
Any Idea

So here is screenshot from my 1st report also:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you only want certain elements filtered, you can group them together with the filters. Any graphs/tables that are not part of the group will not be filtered.